# How do I build custom row that has ListView.Builder inside that builds ElevatedButton in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface, listview, widget

I want to make a screen where there will be a floating action button that calls a function called customRow() which dynamically creates custom Row() widgets based on a string value that I pass in to the function.

here is my customRow() code

```
customRow(int key, String label, TextInputType type, String widget){

    if(widget == "selection"){
      return Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: TextField(
              onChanged: (val){
                onUpdate(key, val);
              },
              keyboardType: type,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: key.toString(),
                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                ),
                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  fontSize: 10.0,
                ),
              ),
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 1.0,),
          SizedBox(
            child: ListView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: (){

                    },
                    child: Text("HELLO"),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: (){

                    },
                    child: Text("HELLO"),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: (){

                    },
                    child: Text("HELLO"),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: (){
              setState(() {
                Map<String, dynamic> tempMap = {};
                for(final element in widgetList) {
                  if(element["id"] == key){
                    tempMap = element;
                    break;
                  }
                }
                widgetList.remove(tempMap);

                for(final element in customTextValuesList) {
                  if(element["id"] == key){
                    tempMap = element;
                    break;
                  }
                }

                customTextValuesList.remove(tempMap);
              });

            },
            child: Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.red,),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
    else{
      return Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: TextField(
              onChanged: (val){
                onUpdate(key, val);
              },
              keyboardType: type,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: key.toString(),
                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                ),
                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  fontSize: 10.0,
                ),
              ),
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 1.0,),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: (){
              setState(() {
                Map<String, dynamic> tempMap = {};
                for(final element in widgetList) {
                  if(element["id"] == key){
                    tempMap = element;
                    break;
                  }
                }
                widgetList.remove(tempMap);

                for(final element in customTextValuesList) {
                  if(element["id"] == key){
                    tempMap = element;
                    break;
                  }
                }

                customTextValuesList.remove(tempMap);
              });

            },
            child: Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.red,),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
  }
```

So when I pass widget parameter as "selection", It should be able to build Elevated buttons that can be horizontally scrollable (since it will have more than one buttons in that row). The "selection" Row() will also have a "+" TextButton() in the end to add additional ElevatedButton() as required.

Now what I want is to draw that Row when I call the customRow() with :selection" as parameter value.

But I am getting error like

```
======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
Horizontal viewport was given unbounded width.

Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container. In this case, a horizontal viewport was given an unlimited amount of horizontal space in which to expand. This situation typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget.

If this widget is always nested in a scrollable widget there is no need to use a viewport because there will always be enough horizontal space for the children. In this case, consider using a Row instead. Otherwise, consider using the "shrinkWrap" property (or a ShrinkWrappingViewport) to size the width of the viewport to the sum of the widths of its children.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ListView file:///D:/Flutter%20Projects/data_entry/lib/AllScreens/voterAddScreen.dart:503:20
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      RenderViewport.computeDryLayout.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1399:15)
#1      RenderViewport.computeDryLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1430:6)
#2      RenderBox.performResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2332:12)
#3      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1758:9)
#4      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
...
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderViewport#fa47f NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(unconstrained)
...  size: MISSING
...  axisDirection: right
...  crossAxisDirection: down
...  offset: ScrollPositionWithSingleContext#f6d00(offset: 0.0, range: null..null, viewport: null, ScrollableState, ClampingScrollPhysics -> RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics, IdleScrollActivity#ef5c4, ScrollDirection.idle)
...  anchor: 0.0
RenderObject: RenderViewport#fa47f NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
  needs compositing
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(unconstrained)
  size: MISSING
  axisDirection: right
  crossAxisDirection: down
  offset: ScrollPositionWithSingleContext#f6d00(offset: 0.0, range: null..null, viewport: null, ScrollableState, ClampingScrollPhysics -> RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics, IdleScrollActivity#ef5c4, ScrollDirection.idle)
  anchor: 0.0
...  center child: RenderSliverPadding#32627 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...    parentData: paintOffset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...    constraints: MISSING
...    geometry: null
...    padding: EdgeInsets.zero
...    textDirection: ltr
...    child: RenderSliverList#e637a NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...      parentData: paintOffset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...      constraints: MISSING
...      geometry: null
...      no children current live
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#fa47f NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1930 pos 12: 'hasSize'


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ListView file:///D:/Flutter%20Projects/data_entry/lib/AllScreens/voterAddScreen.dart:503:20
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      RenderBox.size (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1930:12)
#3      RenderViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1450:39)
#4      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
#5      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#6      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
...
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderViewport#fa47f NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(unconstrained)
...  size: MISSING
...  axisDirection: right
...  crossAxisDirection: down
...  offset: ScrollPositionWithSingleContext#f6d00(offset: 0.0, range: null..null, viewport: null, ScrollableState, ClampingScrollPhysics -> RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics, IdleScrollActivity#ef5c4, ScrollDirection.idle)
...  anchor: 0.0
RenderObject: RenderViewport#fa47f NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
  needs compositing
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(unconstrained)
  size: MISSING
  axisDirection: right
  crossAxisDirection: down
  offset: ScrollPositionWithSingleContext#f6d00(offset: 0.0, range: null..null, viewport: null, ScrollableState, ClampingScrollPhysics -> RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics, IdleScrollActivity#ef5c4, ScrollDirection.idle)
  anchor: 0.0
...  center child: RenderSliverPadding#32627 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...    parentData: paintOffset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...    constraints: MISSING
...    geometry: null
...    padding: EdgeInsets.zero
...    textDirection: ltr
...    child: RenderSliverList#e637a NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...      parentData: paintOffset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...      constraints: MISSING
...      geometry: null
...      no children current live
====================================================================================================

====================================================================================================
```

I call my function like this

```
customRow(_counter, "", TextInputType.text, "selection")
```

I have tried to wrap the Buttons inside a Container(), wrap the entire thing inside Expanded() but nothing works.

The flow of parent widget of the calling function is like this

```
Scaffold -> Stack -> Container-> Column-> Expanded-> ListView.builder -> customRow(_counter...)
```

Comment: try removing `Expanded` Widget from `ListView`.

Comment: What will be the expected parent of the calling method? Does the widget tree contain any Scrollable Widget?

Comment: The flow of widget from which the function is called is like this Scaffold -> Stack - >Container->Column->Expanded->ListView.builder @Nidheesh MT

Comment: "try removing Expanded Widget from ListView" tried this. not working

Comment: try wrapping `ListView` in an `Expanded / Flexible` Widget, and enable  `shrinkWrap: true` of `ListView`,

Comment: maybe because not give size to ListView parent ,use SizedBox not give size(width).

Comment: I have found it out. Thanks for the help. I have answered this question.

Answer (score 0):

I have made it. The entire customRow() code.

```
customRow(int key, String label, TextInputType type, String widget){

    if(widget == "selection"){
      return Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  onChanged: (val){
                    onUpdate(key, val);
                  },
                  keyboardType: type,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: key.toString(),
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14.0,
                    ),
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      fontSize: 10.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 40.0,),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  height: 100.0,
                  child: ListView(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 28.0),
                          child: SizedBox(
                            height: 150.0,
                            child: ListView.builder(
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                itemCount: 5,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index){
                                  return Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Row(
                                        children: [
                                          ElevatedButton(
                                            onPressed: (){},
                                            child: Text("Hello"),
                                          ),
                                          Container(
                                            width: 30.0,
                                            child: TextButton(
                                              onPressed: () {  },
                                              child: Icon(Icons.close),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  );
                                }
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ]
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: (){
                    setState(() {
                      Map<String, dynamic> tempMap = {};
                      for(final element in widgetList) {
                        if(element["id"] == key){
                          tempMap = element;
                          break;
                        }
                      }
                      widgetList.remove(tempMap);

                      for(final element in customTextValuesList) {
                        if(element["id"] == key){
                          tempMap = element;
                          break;
                        }
                      }

                      customTextValuesList.remove(tempMap);
                    });

                  },
                  child: Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.red,),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          DividerWidget(customColor: Colors.blue),
        ],
      );
    }
    else{
      return Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: TextField(
              onChanged: (val){
                onUpdate(key, val);
              },
              keyboardType: type,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: key.toString(),
                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                ),
                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  fontSize: 10.0,
                ),
              ),
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 1.0,),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: (){
              setState(() {
                Map<String, dynamic> tempMap = {};
                for(final element in widgetList) {
                  if(element["id"] == key){
                    tempMap = element;
                    break;
                  }
                }
                widgetList.remove(tempMap);

                for(final element in customTextValuesList) {
                  if(element["id"] == key){
                    tempMap = element;
                    break;
                  }
                }

                customTextValuesList.remove(tempMap);
              });

            },
            child: Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.red,),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
  }
```

[image]